# How to change the color of winform DataGridview header?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have tried to do it without success.

**Is it possible ?**

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The way to do this is to set the `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` flag for the data grid view to `False`, and set the background colour via the `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor` property. For example, to set the background colour to blue, use the following (or set in the designer if you prefer):

```
_dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
_dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

If you do not set the `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` flag to False, then the changes you make to the style of the header will not take effect, as the grid will use the style from the current users default theme. The MSDN documentation for this property is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.enableheadersvisualstyles.aspx?ppud=4).

Comment: +1. Doesn't just work, but explains why you have to do both steps. Nice!

Comment: I put this in the form's load event so that both the column and row headers colors are set when the datagridview is displayed.

Comment: If you want to change only some specific column header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067398/change-specific-column-header-color-only-in-datagridview

Answer (score 14):

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: What's the value of this answer comparing to the accepted one which has more details and 3 years earlier?

Answer (score 8):

It can be done.

From the designer:
Select your DataGridView
Open the Properties
Navigate to ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStype
Hit the button to edit the style.

You can also do it programmatically:

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Purple;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That will not work because you have not disabled the VisualStyles. Any changes to the style will not work because VisualStyles are set to true.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to change a color to single column try this:

```
 dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
 dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 5):

**Always, set `dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;` before styling the column header or row header. then only , the custom styles you made will be applied to row and column header.**

```
     DataGridViewCellStyle column_header_cell_style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                column_header_cell_style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
                column_header_cell_style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                column_header_cell_style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Chocolate;
                column_header_cell_style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                column_header_cell_style.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 18, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);


this.dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = column_header_cell_style;
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. thanks!

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue; 
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set every styles by **Attribute** property.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Attribute["style"]="color:red; padding-top:10px";
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for topleftcell for me:

```cs
DataGridViewCellStyle columnHeaderStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
columnHeaderStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
dataGridViewLabelsFromClient.TopLeftHeaderCell.Style = columnHeaderStyle;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;