# Is it possible to skin Winform DataGridView on XP to look like on Vista

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, skinning

It is possible to change the color of DataGridView Headers ([how to change the color of winform DataGridview header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header)) but still it doesn't seem  enough to look like Vista.

So is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/) provides a powerful way to skin DataGridView and other common WinForms controls.

Comment: PS - The installer also will install their paid components.  Only add a reference to ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit to avoid accidentally using their paid components... unless you want to use them (they are very good)