# Hot to change specific column header color only in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

Uses: VS 2005, C#, DataGridView, WinForms;

I need to color the font/background of a particular column's Header portion. I see that it can only be done to the entire column list's header instead of a single column. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First in your DataGridView you need to set EnableHeadersVisualStyles to false.
After you've done that you can set the individual header style on each column.

```
        DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
        dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
        dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: I was able to change font to bold without changing EnableHeadersVisualStyles to false using dgc.HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font(dgc.HeaderCell.DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold) where dgc is the DataGridViewColumn I'm trying to modify.

Comment: @B H: That works for the Font but not for the Colors.

Answer (score 3):

Do it in this way

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
{
     col.Name = "ColumnName";
     col.HeaderText = "HeaderName";
     col.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
     col.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red; //Column Header Color
     this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a method name called SetUpDataGridView

```
private void SetUpDataGridView()
{
  dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Emp.Id";         
  dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
  dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Emp. Name";
  dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
}
```

Add the method in Form_Load.
You can add different color for every header