# Coloring rows, adding text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a table in Visual Studio Express like this:

[image: Table]

And I'm using a `tableLayoutPanel`. How can I color the first row in a `tableLayoutPanel` with a grayscale style like in the picture and possibly add some text in each cell in the first row?

Comment: ListView control with details select and the first row you fill in columns and it will turn just like that.

Comment: You may have to modify the `Paint` event to achieve coloring like in the picture provided.

Comment: If you use a `DataGridView` then you can just adjust the `ForeColor` and `BackgroundColor` in the `DefaultCellStyle`.  I don't think you have that kind of control with a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Like @Andrew says, this is exactly what `DataGridView` is for.  Is there any reason you can't use that?  I'd add it as an answer, but Andrew you got here first, you should get the credit.

Comment: @Andrew There is `System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel` control in winforms. However I completely agree with your suggestion about DataGridView.

Comment: @Jon- That's very polite!

Answer (score 1):

You can paint specific cells using this event method:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == 0 && e.Column == 1)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.CellBounds);
    }
}
```

Just paint all the cells in the row that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a `DataGridView` where you can color each row separately and set each columns text.

For more information you might want to check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header)

Answer (score 1):

A `DataGridView` would better suit your needs for style customization:

You can set the `BackgroundColor` and `ForeColor` for the `DefaultCellStyle` for any row you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx)?
It looks exactly like your picture, you can place text in any cell and icons in the first column, has a header, an even the grid lines ...

Set its `View` property to `View.Details` to get the desired beavior.