# Change Header Background color on DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with several columns and I want the header row to have a different color.

```
DataGridViewColumn carBrand = dgvCar.Columns["Brand"];
if (carBrand != null)
    carBrand.Width = 180;
carBrand.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
carBrand.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
carBrand.HeaderText = "CAR BRAND";
TagGalp.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = BackColor.Red;
```

It works fine to modify the width of column and text, but I am not able to get the color. What is wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header