# highlight row header for rows with any selected cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want my `DataGridView` to highlight row headers for any rows that have selected cells.  Any way to do that?

(Standard behavior seems to be only to highlight the row header if the entire row of cells is selected).

What I've tried:

I've looked at the decompiled source for DataGridView and from what i can tell (which definitely may be wrong) it highlights the header based upon whether the DataGridViewRow is selected. I can't figure out how to set the row selected without the whole row actually being selected

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at having an event handler for the CellClick or the SelectionChanged events that highlights the relevant headers?

Comment: question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done this before is to handle the `CellStateChanged` event, check the cells in the effected cell's row, and set the row header accordingly.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool selected = false;

    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in e.Cell.OwningRow.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Selected)
        {
            selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    e.Cell.OwningRow.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = selected ?
        this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor :
        this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
}
```

You'll need to set the following snippit to enable these changes, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252013/3773066):

```
this.dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

Not shown: also consider coloring the header cell for `Row[0]` when everything is initialized.

Comment: this looks promising.  don't have time to test yet, but i'll accept it!  appreciate the help!!!

Comment: do you do anything special during initialization?  for some reason my grid initially displays with all row headers selected and afterwards operates as desired.  i think what is happening is that the grid is internally selecting the first cell during the initial display, although i'm not sure how all the row headers wind up selected at first.

Comment: i got it working but i had to guard against executing the logic as the result of an `OnBindingContextChanged` event.  And, it's sweet!

Comment: The only thing I did during initialization (which I did in `Form.Load`) was to set the `DataSource` and other event handlers before setting `EnableHeadersVisualSyles = false`.  I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior you described, so I'm glad you worked it out. :)