# Change color of datagridview rowheader of column header C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to Change color of datagridview rowheader a colum header C# like below:[image]

Comment: The Cell is called TopLeftHeaderCell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Cell` is called `TopLeftHeaderCell` and you can set its `Value` like this:

```
dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "HIHO";
```

It even has a `Style` property with `Colors` etc..but I found that changing the `BackColor` has no effect. That is unless you change this [obscure setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header) to `false`:

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Gold;
```

---

As an alternative you **could** also **ownerdraw** the cell.

Here is an example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 && e.ColumnIndex < 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gold, e.CellBounds);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    ..
```

But why would you ;-)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you. I didn't know the term.