# vbnet listview column header background color

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

how to set the colour of listview column header ?

this is the code of how i set my listview (in detail mode) , I want to set background colour to the header (id, nama , position).

```
   With ListViewEmployee
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("ID", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
        .Columns.Add("Nama", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("Position", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    End With

    If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            With ListViewEmployee
                .Items.Add(table.Rows(i)("IDEmployee"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(table.Rows(i)("Nama"))
                    .Add(table.Rows(i)("Position"))

                End With
            End With
        Next



    End If
```

Comment: Use Google next time, you will get lot of solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header

Comment: The solution you propose is for datagridview