# Breaking Change in DataGridView between .Net 4.0 and .NET 4.7.2 Header Selection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I recently migrated a Project from `.NET 4` to `.NET 4.7.2` which introduced a change in the WinForms DataGridView Headers.

Pre Migration looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the Header of the cell i currently clicked is not selected.
After the Migration the same DataGridView looks like this:
[image]
I could not find any Information mentioning changes in the WinForms DataGridView at the [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)

I tried to set the Color using the following code from here 
    [how to change the color of winform DataGridview header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247800/how-to-change-the-color-of-winform-datagridview-header)

```
this.dgvUserFields.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
this.dgvUserFields.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

But the code does not seem to change anything.

Are the some resources confirming that breaking change, and how to fix it ?

Comment: It's the `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect` mode. It has this feature now (to indicate a cell selection change). I'm not sure this applies to everyone, though.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you have any detailed Information what got changed ? Or some Sources / Solutions

Comment: [.Net release notes - WinForms](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/dotnet472-changes.md#windows-forms). You have to look at the specific issues, marked by a number. This goes under the accessibility improvements. The highligh is tied to the user Theme. Also: [Migration Guide to the .NET Framework 4.7, 4.6, and 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/index)

Comment: You __may__ be able to [opt out](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/Documentation/compatibility/winforms-accessibility-changes-472.md)

Comment: If you don't really need FW 4.7.2, FW 4.7.1., IIRC, doesn't have this feature.

Comment: @TaW thanks very much - sadly the switch seems to be ignored if compiled against 4.7.2. It shows no changes.

Comment: If you set `.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false`, the high level painting does change anything? Something like:  `int AffectedColumns = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Select(ch => ch.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray).Count();`. Or directly painting the headers?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem. What are the settings leading to this behavior?

Comment: @RezaAghaei As Mention in the first Comment - this arises if the SelectionMode of the DataGridView is set to DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect.

Answer (score 10):

The behavior is documented in [What's new in accessibility in the .NET Framework 4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility#whats-new-in-accessibility-in-the-net-framework-472)
 in *DataGridView improvements* section:

> When the [`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SelectionMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_SelectionMode) is set to
>   [`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectionmode#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewSelectionMode_FullRowSelect),
>   the column header will change color to indicate the current column as
>   the user tabs through the cells in the current row.

In .NET Framework 4.7.2 when rendering `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, it checks if the column `IsHighlighted`, then it renders the column in pushed state and here is the logic to detect `IsHighlighted`:

```
private bool IsHighlighted()
{
    return this.DataGridView.SelectionMode == DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect && 
        this.DataGridView.CurrentCell != null && this.DataGridView.CurrentCell.Selected &&
        this.DataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == this.OwningColumn &&
        AccessibilityImprovements.Level2;
}
```

As you can see in above code, there is `&& AccessibilityImprovements.Level2`. It means if you turn the feature off, the behavior will be reset.

As also mentioned in the comments by [Taw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513396/breaking-change-in-datagridview-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-7-2-header-selection/51519701#comment89997315_51513396), you can turn the feature off. To do so, you can add this block of setting to `app.config` file:

```
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=true" />
</runtime>
```

Comment: By chance, have you tested whether something like what I asked in the comments (directly/indirectly painting the headers) can override this behaviour? I'ld test it myself, but I don't have a single machine with 4.7.2 at the moment.

Comment: @Jimi Of course custom paint can be a solution. For example, using a visual style renderer for header item in `CellPainting` event: `if(e.RowIndex==-1){ renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds);
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & (~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background));
    e.Handled = true; }` But to keep the user look and feel like what it was, the OP needs a bit more effort, for example to handle header states (hot, normal, pressed).

Comment: Of course. It came to mind (4.7.2 in test drive next week) that the new behaviour, given its nature, could have also superseded a custom rendering. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't like to ship an app.config together with my standalone executables, I use these lines at the beginning of my Main() in program.cs to disable the "improvements":

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.3", true);
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2", true);
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:

```
this.dgvUserFields.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = this.dgvUserFields.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  In the Properties window of your grid:

1. set your desired ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle to whatever you want your header to look like.
2. set EnableHeaderVisualStyles = false

Answer (score 1):

dgvUserFields.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

> **add this in form load event**

Answer (score 0):

Addition to [Reza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51519701/594832):

As of the advent of .NET Framework 4.8 there is a new accessibility improvements level: `AccessibilityImprovements.Level3`

So when adding this to your app.config:

```xml
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=true" />
</runtime>
```

Then you'll probably face this exception during startup of your application:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Desktop applications are required to opt in to all earlier accessibility improvements to get the later improvements. To do this, ensure that if the AppContext switch 'Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.N' is set to 'false', then 'Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures' and all 'Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.M' switches, when M < N, evaluate to false as well. Note that, if a switch for a particular set of accessibility improvements is not present, its value is determined by the target framework version. You can remedy this by adding these switches and setting their value to false.'

To solve this, you have to opt-out of level 3 as well:

```xml
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=true;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.3=true" />
</runtime>
```

Please note:

If you have applied the [KB4569746 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 4.8](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=4569746), then you'll probably have to opt-out of level 4, too.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the "improvements" did work, but it caused other issues for some reason.

I had a few forms with the issue and will also be adding more as the application grows. So I created my own custom DataGridView to handle the DataGridView's ColumnStateChanged event and reset the HeaderCell's Style to the default background value, so that I do not have to add this line/handle event on each new form.

1. Create a custom DataGridView to be used by your application.
2. In the constructor, you can handle the DataGridView's ColumnStateChanged event and reset the HeaderCell's Style to the default background value:

e.g (I actualy already had a custom grid for other reasons like search filtering):

```
public class DataGridViewCustom : DataGridView
  {
    public DataGridViewSearch() : base()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
  
      this.ColumnStateChanged += DataGridViewCustom_ColumnStateChanged;
    }
  
    private void DataGridViewCustom_ColumnStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      DataGridView dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
      //Only update for full row selection mode.
      if (dataGridView.SelectionMode == DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect)
      {
        e.Column.HeaderCell.Style.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a Cell_Painting event handler and set back the original color:

In this example I check if the e.FormattedValue matches the text of the column header for which I want to remove the highlight. Then I simply set back the original color.

```
    private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.FormattedValue == "HeaderTextValue")
        {
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240, 240);
        }
    }
```