# How to disable the column header selection when a row is clicked in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'd like to disable the selection backcolor of my column header (see picture, red circled, column2). I also like to keep the SelectionMode of the DGV to `FullRowSelect`.
And I also wish that the colum header backcolor stays different of the row selectionbackcolor.

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: [Breaking Change in DataGridView between .Net 4.0 and .NET 4.7.2 Header Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51519701/3110834)

Comment: Amazing, thanks ! I add this to app.config and now it's like I want 
<runtime>
  <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures=false;Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures.2=true" />
</runtime>