# How can I stop my datagridview column headers from having a different selection color?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, highlight

I have a DataGridView object I set up with a few columns.  After filling it with data and clicking on a cell in the data (ex: A2 in this case that has a red box around it in the image) it seems to highlight the column header in a light blue.

[image]

How can I stop this?

I have tried things like...

```
// Background selection color on items in the data
DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

// Background selection color defaults for headers
DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

// Disable visual styles
DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

// Background selection color defaults for headers set to WHITE
DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;

// Background selection color defaults for header zero set to WHITE
DataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
```

Nothing seems to be getting rid of that highlight.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF ?

Comment: @jeb: [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) is part of WinForms. In WPF, one uses [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Comment: Thanks @user09938, I also added the winforms tag too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
DataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

Alternate way is to simply match colors

```
DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Control;
```

The headers shouldn't be highlighted after.

Comment: Ahh so you needed both the visual styles disabled and the selectionbackcolor set!  Nice thanks!

Comment: As @ArvoBowen mentioned, I also only got it to work by disabling the header styles AND setting the back color to the normal ones.

Comment: For anyone going crazy, this behavior does not occur in .NET 4.6.1. I don't know which exact framework made this change but it's extremely unfortunate as when you disable header visual styles you lose things like: hover mouse color change and column divider border. You'd have to render this all yourself. Frankly a terrible change that it can't be disabled.

Comment: Here's the real answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513396/breaking-change-in-datagridview-between-net-4-0-and-net-4-7-2-header-selection